# java programming get last integer not zero

Tags: java

i am a new to java program i have a simple problem like this:

i try this one

```
int sum=1;

    int x=0;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("input number");
     int num=in.nextInt();

     for(int i=1 ;i<=num;i++)
     {
         sum=sum*i;
    }
     {
         System.out.println("the sum is of all number from 1 to"+" "+num+" "+"is:"+sum);
     }

     int last=sum % 10;

     {
       System.out.print("the last number is: "+last); 
     }
```

but i want to print the last integer not equal to 0

Comment: Your calculation of the "sum" is not correct.

Comment: What you WANT to do? You're printing zero becuase % (mod), so, if the sum is equal a even number, when you get the rest of divsion by 10 is equal zero.

Comment: Also by doing `last = sum % 10` you're assuming that the "sum" has 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

To print the last digit not equal to 0:

```
System.out.print("the last number is: " + (num+"").replaceAll(".*([1-9])0*", "$1"));
```

The inportant part of this answer is the regex in the call to `replaceAll()`. It matches the entire input, while capturing the last non-zero digit as group 1. The replacement term is a back-reference to group 1, so the whole input is replaced by the last non-zero digit, effectively extracting it.

This will still work if the number is zero - the result will be unchanged because there will be no match.

This could have been achieved by first removing all trailing zeroes, then using substring to get the last digit, but it would have taken move lines of code and you would have to add extra code for the zero number edge case, although it may possibly be more understandable.

Comment: Explanation might help him a lot.. that's not an easy answer :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I thought someone may say something like that. My response is that my answer is as clear as his question :)

Comment: well the real problem given is i have to compute the sum of all given number for example i have an input : 5 so that is 1x2x3x4x5 which equal to 120 then i will print the last digit but if the last digit is 0 i will print the 2 .

Comment: That's what my code does. Try it in your program and see if it works for you

Comment: @Bohemian This might be what they "deserved" but c'mon man. This is SO. If an asker doesn't have any standards, at least the answerer can uphold them.

Comment: @AnubianNoob too obscure to be useful to the asker? Probably. OK I have added some explanation of what's going on. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Bohemian That's what I meant; now it makes sense. What I was trying to say is kinda that sure the question made no sense, but that doesn't give the answerer free reign to do the same. Especially a mod. We look up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your sum variable actually contains the product of all values.

To retrieve the last nonzero value you can do:

```
if (sum == 0)
{
    System.out.print("no last number found"); 
}
else
{
    int last=sum%10;
    while (last == 0)
    {
        sum /= 10;
        last =sum%10;
    }

    System.out.print("the last number is: "+last); 
}
```